# Free memory allocated to parameter pointer

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

Suppose I have a function

```
int myfunction(char *s)
```

In this function, the string pointed to by `s` gets manipulated, and the `return` value is an error code.

Suppose the pointer passed already pointed to `malloc()` memory. Is it my responsibility (developing a library) to free this memory at the top of the function, or is it the library user's fault for not knowing that this function will be making a call to `malloc()` or related and setting `s` to point there instead?

Comment: I don't understand what's going on. Who is calling `malloc()`? You? The user? Why do you want to free something that the user presumably wants to consume later?

Comment: "this function will be making a call to malloc() or related and setting s to point there instead?" - smells like misunderstanding. Setting the pointer *inside* the function **will not** change it, and this it's *your* function that will leak memory. You don't even need to malloc anything at all if `s` is valid when passed to your function (as it definitely should be).

Comment: Wel.. usually.  It depends if the function is going to assume ownership of the string passed, eg. by queueing the pointer off to an internal thread).  Still, you are right - the pointer is passed by value and library cannot magically change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual contract is the person doing the `malloc` is the person doing the `free`.

Also consider that the data pointed to may not have been `malloc`'ed in the first place. Could be on the stack

Comment: @KerrekSB - Poor language on my part

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is not to modify the string, it should be declared `const`:

```
int myfunction(const char *s);
```

Then it's clear that `myfunction()` won't assume ownership and try to deallocate the string (you can't call `free()` with a `const` pointer) which is the typical approach.

Since the called function can't know if the string is dynamically allocated or not, it doesn't make sense for it to assume ownership.

Comment: If it does take ownership, it should be made very clear in the documentation that the buffer/string must be dynamically allocated and the caller must not free it.

Comment: It is just false negative (or positive, not sure) of ownership non-transfer, because absense of const does not mean the inverse. And actually it is very rare case when you do this -- interfaces should not be unable to work with non-dynamic strings (and objects in general). Making a dynamic copy is usually a consumer's job, not producer's.

Comment: The problem with that is, well, it needs a copy operation that may be avoided.  If you have assembled, already at at great cost, a 10MB buffer, not copying it is a petty good gain.  What might seem like the 'correct way' is occcasionally a really bad idea.

Comment: It's an even worse idea if a thread-lock has to be held during the copy.  A lock round a pointer copy is O(1).

Answer (score 0):

Well, if we look at various apis, then we will get an idea. For example, `strdup()` where we pass `const char *s` as an argument, `strdup()` takes the responsibility of allocating the memory. On the other hand you will also find examples where functions usually don't 
take responsibility of allocating buffer i.e `fgets()` (there are lot more). There's also functions available which allows both, `getline()` for an example. From the man page of 
`getline()`:

```
  If *lineptr is NULL, then getline() will allocate a buffer for storing the line
  ,which should be freed by the user  program. (In this case, the value in *n is
  ignored.)

  Alternatively,  before  calling  getline(), *lineptr can contain a pointer to a
  malloc(3)-allocated buffer *n bytes in size.
```

So, all the approaches are valid. One thing that you must have to maintain is
*documentation*. If should implement it properly (don't forget to think about various consequences) and let it's user know what that particular function does. It's your fault if you don't provide the documentation and it's users responsibility to know how that particular function works.